# Qualtrics: Dynamically adjusting max value of slider

Tags: qualtrics

I'm a newbie to Qualtrics.

Please assume the following situation

In Qid1, subject report some value x

In Qid2, subject reports through slider which has a value [0,x]

Could someone help me out how to code this up?

---

This is what I tried. (I just want to customize the min and max of the slider through J query but still, it is difficult for me)

```
    Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()
    {
       jQuery("#QID58\~1\~true-result").prop('min',1);
       jQuery("#QID58\~1\~true-result").prop('max',10);
    });

    Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnReady(function()
    {
       jQuery("#QID58\~1\~true-result").prop('min',1);
       jQuery("#QID58\~1\~true-result").prop('max',10);
    });
```

Could someone give me a guidance to get through?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! In order for us to help you, it would be very beneficial if you could please provide example of the output you expect. Also try to provide a more readable input if possible. Finally, have you tried anything from which we can help you? The objective in this forum is for us to help once you get stuck while coding, not to provide a sample code. Maybe a tutorial is the best way to go here?

Comment: Thank you Antonio! I will write down again