# Qualtrics: Custom slider range with embedded data using javascript

Tags: javascript, qualtrics

I want to create one single slider in Qualtrics where the min, the MAX and the intervals are chosen according to 4 different embedded data. I need help with the Javascript.

**Why do I need one single slider?** I need a single slider because I have 16 questions in total, and it is easier to recall 16 questions ID rather than 64 different questions ID.
**How should the slider change?** I need the slider MAX to be either 1, 10, 100 or 177. Moreover, I always need to have 100 possible choices. Therefore, I need to introduce 2, 1, 0 and 0 decimals, respectively.
**Why Javascript?** Qualtrics does not allow dynamic custom slider values.

What I have tried so far:

1. I tried using the default options, but they are not helpful.
2. I tied looking for resolved questions on StackOverflow but only found this thread: [Qualtrics: Dynamically adjusting max value of slider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58961815/qualtrics-dynamically-adjusting-max-value-of-slider)

Answer (score 0):

What your post asks is not a specific question, but rather an entire project. To aid you in this, I have broken up your question into subproblems, all of which can be resolved with simple googling.

First, set up your slider so that it ranges from 0 to 100 - that will ensure that the user always has 100 options. You can then perform a calculation to adjust that to any range you would like based on your embedded data (information how to get embedded data in JS can be found in [this post](https://community.qualtrics.com/XMcommunity/discussion/199/using-javascript-with-embedded-data-and-or-selected-choices) or on the [Qualtrics JS API](https://api.qualtrics.com/82bd4d5c331f1-qualtrics-java-script-question-api-class)). For more information on how to scale to any rage, here's [a good place to start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5294955/how-to-scale-down-a-range-of-numbers-with-a-known-min-and-max-value). This calculation is critical as you will use it later on to set the exact value of the grid lines (i.e. intervals) as well as the displayed value (if you opt to display value).

**NB**: Unfortunately, you are forced to set up the slider to range from 0-100, as you cannot set up more than 20 grid lines. If you could, you could have just set up 100 grid lines and removed the grid lines values and used labels instead for guidance, but there you go.

Next, start with a slider that has a single grid line in the options. You can now adjust these grid lines to your `intervals`. Specifically, to get the field where these gridlines are defined, get the `ul` with class name `numbers` in your slider question. This could look something like this:

```js
let numbers = document.getElementById('QID1').getElementsByClassName('numbers')[0]
```

This `numbers` variable will now contain an HTML element with its children being a list of `li` elements, with each defining a different interval - calculate those interval however your heart desires and add them to the `numbers` element on the DOM. Tip: to see how this works, play around by examining the DOM when you vary the number of grid lines. Hint: careful when you set the widths (as this is your property to calculate) - for 2 grid lines or 4, all of the `li` elements have a `width` of 50 or 25, respectively, but for 11 grid lines the two `li` elements with classes `first` and `last` have `width` of 5 and the rest of the in-between `li` elements have a `width` of 10.

To customize the number that is shown in those intervals (to however many decimal places you want), adjust the `innerHTML` of those `li` elements.

Your next step is to make sure that if you do end up showing the value to the participant, then that value can only be a "legit" value. After all, we set the slider from 0 to 100, but it could be 50 to 250 and it must only show values 50-52-54 etc. To achieve that, find the element that displays the value and overwrite it with your calculation (the current value scaled to your desired range). To find the elements, use something like this:

```js
document.getElementById('QID1~1~toolTipBox')
```

This will look for question with ID `QID1` and then look at the first choice's `toolTipBox`. Overwrite the contest by change its `innerHTML`.

Finally, don't forget to adjust your data when you process it later on. After all, you have access to all embedded fields in the data, simply scale those to get the actual values (as the ones you will get will most likely be 0-100, though I am not 100% sure how Qualtrics decides what value to save in the data).